# MVC frameworks, API layers, and Authentication/Permissions

Tags: php, model-view-controller, api, authentication, permissions

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093813/mvc-style-application-architecture-catering-to-api) earlier, however it may have been too vague or broad to warrant an answer. I've since reconsidered my approach and my question.

I'm working on a framework with specific application in mind, but obviously am keeping re-usability at the forefront. The key element of this framework is exposing an API layer, for JSON driven remote interaction.

My issue in planning this out comes with **authentication/permissions**. *If I'm designing with an MVC style architecture in mind, yet want to permit usage via the API layer, where should the authentication/permissions check take place?*

The web access layer is essentially the same as API layer, the only difference being the output method (HTML vs. JSON), so I figured a common business logic layer for the two would make sense. Requests would be normalized to a data structure, and sent to the business logic. The business logic ultimately kicks out a result data structure (query results, failure, success, etc.) that is either fed to the Template engine, or serialized to JSON.

It appears to me that the permissions check needs to be performed in the common business logic layer, but is there a better place to incorporate this into an MVC/API framework?

I don't know where else to elaborate at the moment, so feel free to ask for more details and I'll provide as I come up with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you plan on allowing users to access the API?

Here's how I do role-based authorization:

- Each controller typically has multiple actions (methods) that are accessible to the frontend, e.g.

  - `function action_get($id)`
  - `function action_delete($id)`
- Each controller has a class property that specifies which roles are required for each action, e.g.

  ```
  protected $access = array(
      'get' => NULL,  // everybody can access; this line isnt necessary though
      'delete' => array('admin')  // only admins can access
  )
  ```
- A `before()` method is fired before executing an action. It does the authorization check based on the $access list.
- Each action is responsible for determining what to output, e.g.

```
public function action_get($id) {
      // Business logic... build data structure
      # ...

      if (Request::is_ajax()) {
          // Output JSON
      }
      else {
          // Output HTML
      }
  }
```

That system could easily be expanded to allow for API calls. Either expand on the output portion of the method, detecting if its an API request, or simply create another action specifically for the API call. If you choose the latter method and wish to keep your code DRY, move the business logic for the data structure to a helper method (e.g. `protected function _get()`).  There may be better ways of providing access to and handling the API as well.. it really depends on how you want to allow access and how flexible/dry you want to make it.

Comment: Thanks **simshaun**; This seems an appropriate solution. The role based permissions you've suggested appears to fit my situation. I can remove output format responsibility from the Controller, since the resulting data structure should be well-formed for both Template insertion or JSON serialization. The reason for the API layer is for both an app, and associated sites, to fetch, modify, or sync data. I'm reluctant to accept only because I'll elaborate on a few other points in my question shortly.

Answer (score 1):

In general, authentication is performed at the controller level (usually in a constructor of the controller class so it's called for every method in that controller). You would of course have some of the user/role data in models, but the controller is what would compare the request to the permissions, etc. and either allow the method or not (and then the method would decide to output html, json, or whatever).

Comment: controller level is the business level.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response **Jordan Lev**; I see what you're saying there. I think my problem in understanding how to accomplish this is that I'm straying from the MVC concept on a few levels that I haven't gone into complete detail on. Hmm, I'll elaborate after whiteboarding a bit more.